# Self Join for adding another column to table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using bunch of nested selects, joins and outer apply to get this result,

```
 ╔═════╦════════╦══════════╦ 
 ║ ID  ║ Name   ║ RandomID ║ 
 ╠═════╬════════╬══════════╬ 
 ║ 1   ║ a      ║     3    ║ 
 ║ 2   ║ b      ║     2    ║ 
 ║ 3   ║ c      ║     1    ║ 
 ╚═════╩════════╩══════════╩
```

What I want,

```
 ╔═════╦════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦ 
 ║ ID  ║ Name   ║ RandomID ║ Random Name  ║
 ╠═════╬════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬
 ║ 1   ║ a      ║     3    ║     c        ║
 ║ 2   ║ b      ║     2    ║     b        ║
 ║ 3   ║ c      ║     1    ║     a        ║
 ╚═════╩════════╩══════════╩══════════════╩
```

So if query prototype is,

```
Select ID, Name, dbo.SomeFunction(@ID)
FROM (Tables + Joins)
WHERE xxx
```

Now should I do inner join to the table which has   ID and Name and get Random Name column from there or should I SOMEHOW join above query ?

I would like to keep performance in mind.

Comment: Without knowing your table structure and what tables you are currently referencing in the query, we have no chance in helping you.

Comment: Not quite sure what exactly is your problem. If you have ID, Name, RandomID table where RandomID is reference to the same table - then your desired result can be achieved by simple self-join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use a CTE:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.id, t.name, t.randomid, trand.name as randomname
from t left join
     t trand
     on t.randomid = trand.id;
```

By using a CTE, you don't need to repeat your logic multiple times or use a temporary table.

Comment: This appears elegant, but can be horrendously inefficient for larger data sets as the CTE is expanded as a sub query in every location where it is referenced. When efficiency is paramount then a temporary table is the correct answer.

Comment: I had to use Left join to get desired result, unless I am missing some concept here ?

Comment: @PleaseTeach . . . That would mean that you have random ids that do not match back to the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's not right, they actually are from same table, getting them through sub select queries, maybe it has got to do something with my outer apply in a sub select query which I didn't added here, but thanks for your helpful answer as it helped

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work for you:

```
select t1.ID
     , t1.Name
     , t1.RandomId
     , t2.Name as RandomName
from tbl t1
join tbl t2 on t1.RandomID = t2.ID
```

Comment: I tried your answer but for some reason it doesn't seem to like the syntax I am applying to it, I am not sure what's tbl and how my existing query going to fit your syntax. thanks for the time though